# Akka-http Java API sample code/documentation

Tags: java, httpclient, akka, akka-http

Could anyone point me to a working sample of akka-http using the JAVA API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Documentation is still mostly missing. You can find examples for Java and Java 8 in the sources, here https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/release-2.3-dev/akka-http-java-tests/src and here https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/release-2.3-dev/akka-http-java8-tests/src

Comment: Previous links are dead, new one is https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/release-2.3-dev/akka-http-core/src/test/java/akka/http/javadsl/model/JavaTestServer.java

Answer (score 3):

This is a small application to demo the concepts:
https://github.com/J-Technologies/akka-http-java